# How to manually shutdown a socket server?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple socket server, how do I shut it down when I enter "shutdown" in the terminal on the server side?

```
import socket 

SERVER = "xxxx"
PORT = 1234
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_connection(conn, addr):
    ... 

server.listen()
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    handle_connection(conn, addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Close active connections and exit. It can be done with:

```py
server.close()
exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To **shutdown** you socket server manually by calling `server.close()`, you whole code should be:

```
import socket 

SERVER = "xxxx"
PORT = 1234
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_connection(conn, addr):
    ... 

server.listen()
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    handle_connection(conn, addr)

#  call server.close() to shut down your server.
```